# Panel data in long format

Tags: r

I have two data frames:

`d1`:

```
 Id group  occu  D  Year
 12     1    1  12  2007
 13     4    2  67  2007
 14     6    3  34  2007
 15     7    1  88  2007
 16     2    2  72  2007
 17     1    1  43  2007
 18     4    1  66  2007
```

and `d2`:

```
    Id group  occu  D Year
   12     1    1  34  2010
   13     4    2 100  2010
   14     6    3  76  2010
   15     7    1  99  2010
   16     2    2 102  2010
   17     1    1  55  2010
   18     4    1  32  2010
```

The variables "`group`"  and "`occu`" are `factors` I want to make a `panel data` for the year 2007 and 2010 in the long form in R.

How can I do this?

Comment: *Panel data in long format*... i.e. `rbind(d1, d2)`?

Comment: yes But is it possible in reshape2?

Comment: Why? You don't need to `melt`. Your dataframes are both in long format

Comment: Will rbind(d1, d2) give me the same effect as molted data frame if data were a one data frame?